Lock down and share exactly same database connection instance between multiple Apache NiFi processors
I am learning and trying to use NiFi to solve data transferring tasks. Now I have a requirement to lock down a same database connection instance between multiple processors.
My flow steps like this:

read data from source database
create a temp table in target database
insert data into the temp table
call a database function in target database to process and then drop the temp table

The 2, 3, 4 steps in the above steps require that its respective processors are in one same database connection session in order to share the temp table.
How could I ensure that?

There is no such option (as i know). Nifi is using DBCP - Database Connection Pool - which gives you a random database connection. Think about a permanent table with some flowfile-id field. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Ok, I got it. permanent table.
